# Django oscar api overwrite child serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-oscar

How can i overwrite oscar api ***ChildProductserializer***.
I followed oscar api guide how to overwrite serializers but i cant overwrite  this one serializer

*Oscar api Child Serializer*

```
class ChildProductserializer(PublicProductSerializer):
    "Serializer for child products"
    parent = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    view_name="product-detail",
    queryset=Product.objects.filter(structure=Product.PARENT),
    )
    # the below fields can be filled from the parent product if enabled.
    images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, required=False, source="parent.images")
    description = serializers.CharField(source="parent.description")

    class Meta(PublicProductSerializer.Meta):
        fields = overridable(
            "OSCARAPI_CHILDPRODUCTDETAIL_FIELDS",
            default=(
            "url",
            "upc",
            "id",
            "title",
            "structure",
            # 'parent', 'description', 'images', are not included by default, but
            # easily enabled by overriding OSCARAPI_CHILDPRODUCTDETAIL_FIELDS
            # in your settings file
            "date_created",
            "date_updated",
            "recommended_products",
            "attributes",
            "categories",
            "product_class",
            "price",
            "availability",
            "options",
            ),
        )
```

*My overwrite  child Serializer*

```
class ChildProductSerializer(product.ChildProductserializer):
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    availability = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta(product.ChildProductserializer.Meta):
        fields=('url','parent','price','availability')
        # 'price','availability','parent')
    def get_price(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        strategy = Selector().strategy(request=request, user=request.user)

        ser = checkout.PriceSerializer(
            strategy.fetch_for_product(instance).price,
            context={'request': request})
        return ser.data
    def get_availability(self,instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        strategy = Selector().strategy(request=request, user=request.user)
        ser = product.AvailabilitySerializer(
        strategy.fetch_for_product(instance).availability,
        context={'request': request}
    )
    return ser.data
    class ProductLinkSerializer(product.ProductLinkSerializer):
        price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        availability = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        class Meta(product.ProductLinkSerializer.Meta):
            fields = ('url','children')
    # ,'id','children','price','title','images','description','children','structure','availability')

    def get_price(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        strategy = Selector().strategy(request=request, user=request.user)

    ser = checkout.PriceSerializer(
        strategy.fetch_for_product(instance).price,
        context={'request': request})
    return ser.data

    def get_availability(self,instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        strategy = Selector().strategy(request=request, user=request.user)
        ser = product.AvailabilitySerializer(
        strategy.fetch_for_product(instance).availability,
        context={'request': request}
    )
    return ser.data
```

but even Meta fields is not working and api display default fields
I have got only problem with this one serializer because overwriting ProductLinkSerializer and OptionSerializer in the same file  is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Going off a limb here because your question isn't really clear, so I assume you mean the meta fields are not showing as intended and you only see default fields.

Basically, since you are inheriting the ChildProductserializer, I'd suggest you should also add the fields from this serializer.

```
class Meta(product.ChildProductserializer.Meta):
    fields= product.ChildProductserializer.Meta + ('url','parent','price','availability')
```

This way, you would override the fields. Remember you are to **override** not **overwrite**